# How do you export a list of PC names and a specific group membership of that endpoint using powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of end points and we are trying to see if they have this specific group membership but I cannot figure out how to export the endpoint and the group its a member of.

```
$Groups = foreach ($pc in (Get-Content "C:\Users\*\Desktop\DefualtTest.csv")) {
    try {
        Get-ADComputer $pc -Properties memberof |
            select -Expand memberof |
            dsget group -samid |
            ? {$_ -match 'bit9'}
    } catch {
        Write-Output "$pc does not have bit9 group"
    }
}

$Groups | Out-File "C:\Users\*\Desktop\testONE.csv"
```

Comment: what is `dsget` doing in that pipeline? i don't see that you are giving it anything to get ... [*grin*] ///// also, don't you already have the group names in the previous step? why not check that against the `bit9` value? ///// also also, your catch is polluting the output stream - that msg will NOT work in a CSV file. ///// finally, the `$Groups` variable looks like it will be an array of strings [group names]. that will NOT export to CSV unless you give it a `-Header` parameter.

Comment: Would something like this work? I am still getting an error                             `Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Users\*\Desktop\DefualtTest.csv"
ForEach ($computer in $computers)
{
  Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties memberOf | Select-Object -Property @{ Name = $computer; Groups=$computer.Memberof } | ? {$_ -match 'bit9'}  | export-csv -path "C:\Users\*\Desktop\TESTTHREE.csv" -append
}`

Comment: test each line! [*grin*] i would do away with the silly internal pipeline so that you can test each section as a single line. then use `Where-Object` to find the `bit9` groups. last, build a `[PSCustomObject]` instead of using `Select-Object` to build the output items. ///// i don't have any access to the AD stuff, so i can't test that.

Comment: unfortunately I do not know how to make my own psobjects.  When I break this down into chunks it works separately.  It states the name key has no value.

Comment: let me back up a tad ... what is in the CSV file? you are using `Get-Content` and that will NOT return an array of objects - instead it returns an array of lines of text.

Comment: It only contains a list of computer names. No special formatting or headers or anything

Comment: ok, so it is NOT an actual CSV file. [*grin*]  then why are you doing `Groups=$computer.Memberof` later on? ///// seriously, DO NOT use the pipeline inside that foreach loop. build each step in one line & save the results to a $Var, confirm that the $Var has what you expect. then do the next step - keeping the $Vars for each step independent of each other so that you can test what each is doing. ///// don't save ANYTHING to the output file until you have a working bit of code ... and save the code results to a $Collection that you `Export-CSV` after the entire loop has finished.

Comment: I mean the extension is cvs but yes its nothing but a list. one item per line. My overall goal is  to find which bit9 group each PC is tied to. I would love for it to export it as "PC Name - Bi9 group" per line and preferably in two separate cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying to do this in comments is ... to difficult. [*grin*]

here's an example of what i mean by "do it one line at a time" in the `foreach` loop ...

```
# fake reading a list of systems from a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$ComputerList = @'
pc01
pc02
pc03
pc04
pc05
pc666
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

# fake getting a list of Computers & the groups they are in
#    in real life, use Get-ADComputer & the ".MemberOf" property
$GroupMembershipLookup = @{
    'pc01' = @('GroupA', 'GroupB')
    'pc02' = @('GroupB', 'GroupC', 'GroupD')
    'pc03' = @('GroupA', 'GroupB', 'GroupE')
    'pc04' = @('GroupZ')
    }

$NoGroupFound = '__No Group Found__'

$Results = foreach ($CL_Item in $ComputerList)
    {
    # use a real call to Get-ADComputer here [*grin*]
    #    pro'ly something like "(Get-ADComputer $CL_Item -Property MemberOf).MemberOf -join '; '"
    $GroupList = $GroupMembershipLookup[$CL_Item] -join '; '
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($GroupList))
        {
        $GroupList = $NoGroupFound
        }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $CL_Item
        GroupMembership = $GroupList
        }
    }

# on screen 
$Results

# to CSV
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\Del_GroupMembershipList.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

on screen output ...

```
ComputerName GroupMembership       
------------ ---------------       
pc01         GroupA; GroupB        
pc02         GroupB; GroupC; GroupD
pc03         GroupA; GroupB; GroupE
pc04         GroupZ                
pc05         __No Group Found__    
pc666        __No Group Found__
```

csv content ...

```
"ComputerName","GroupMembership"
"pc01","GroupA; GroupB"
"pc02","GroupB; GroupC; GroupD"
"pc03","GroupA; GroupB; GroupE"
"pc04","GroupZ"
"pc05","__No Group Found__"
"pc666","__No Group Found__"
```

what the above does ...

- creates an array of system names *as if* they had been read in via `Get-Content`
- creates a lookup table *as if* one had used `Get-ADComputer` to get the group membership for each system
- made a "not found" value & stored that in a $Var for reuse
- iterated thru the `$ComputerList` collection
- grabbed the list/array of groups and converted them into a semicolon delimited string
- tested for "no groups found" & added the value saved earlier if the list was empty
- built a `[PSCustoObject]` and sent that to the output stream
- captured the output stream to an array named `$Results` ***all at one time*** to avoid the `+=` array penalty
- displayed the results on screen
- sent the `$Results` collection to a CSV file

Comment: I am not familiar with your syntax for pc list  or groupmembership look up.... Would it look like this?  `$ComputerList = get-content "C:\Users\a175634\Desktop\DefualtTest.csv" @'

'@ -split [environment]::NewLine`

Comment: @Del - nope! [*grin*] just replace the _entire_ section after the `=` sign with a standard call to `Get-Content`. the code i used is a `Here String` with a split on the newlines to get an array of lines. it is a handy way to imitate the result of a standard `Get-Content` without the need for making a file to import. the usual output of `Get-Content` is an array of lines ... [*grin*]

Comment: awesome! It kind of works but its very very messy. Is there a way to only include the ones that have the bit9 AD group?

Comment: this line `$GroupList = $GroupMembershipLookup[$CL_Item] -join '; '` can also include a test to see if the `.MemberOf` list includes any matches for your `bit9` group. right now, it simply emulates getting the `.MemberOf` list from an ADUser object. you can easily use a `Where-Object` call to filter for only the group/groups you want.